# VBA debugging "Expected: ="

Tags: vba, ms-access

```
Function PrintTableDefs()

Dim aDB As DAO.Database
Dim aTD As DAO.TableDef
Dim aTableName As String
Dim aForeignTableName As String
Dim aString As String
Dim count As Integer

Set count = 0
Set aDB = CurrentDb()

For Each aTD In aDB.TableDefs
  Debug.Print aTD.Name
  Debug.Print aTD.Connect
  Debug.Print ""
  count = count + 1
Next
Debug.Print "There are " & count & "table defs."

End Function
```

When calling this function I get "Compile Error: Expected: =". I have noticed through other questions it is related to parentheses however being mildly unfamiliar with VBA I'm unsure where my syntax is off.

Comment: Except for the `Set` command that @Alex mentions (which throws a compile error) it worked fine on mine.  It will also count the system tables as well - `MSysACEs`, etc (any table starting with `MSys`).  Rather than use the `count` variable you could use `aDB.TableDefs.Count`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `set` from `set count = 0`

`set` is only for assigning object references and an Integer is not an object instance.

Comment: I tried using set to see if it would help, I just removed it. Same error still.

Comment: Your code worked fine for me in Access 2016, on what line do you see the error?

Comment: It must be due to another function in my Module, I'll just create a new module so I can test this function. Thanks for your help Alex.

Answer (score 0):

Alex pointed out the only issue in your function that could throw a compile error:  you don't need a `set` to initialize your `count` variable, because it is not an object. The rest is correct and should not throw an error, so it is elsewhere.

However your code shows that you don't really understand what is the difference between a `sub` and a `function` and it might be helpful to explain it.

A `function` returns a value, a `sub` doesn't. That's what's make them different.
You are not returning any value so you should use a `sub`.
Although your code works fine, because functions that doesn't return a value are accepted by the VBA compiler, it is semantically incorrect and a bad programming habit.

You can make a  proper function out of it by returning the number of tables you found (your count variable)

```
Sub test()
 Debug.Print "There are " & PrintTableDefs() & " table defs."

End Sub

Function PrintTableDefs() As Integer

    Dim aDB As DAO.Database
    Dim aTD As DAO.TableDef
    Dim aTableName As String
    Dim aForeignTableName As String
    Dim aString As String
    Dim count As Integer

    count = 0
    Set aDB = CurrentDb

    For Each aTD In aDB.TableDefs
      Debug.Print aTD.Name
      Debug.Print aTD.Connect
      Debug.Print ""
      count = count + 1
    Next
    PrintTableDefs = count

End Function
```

And if you don't need anything to be returned, make a sub:

```
Sub PrintTableDefs()

    Dim aDB As DAO.Database
    Dim aTD As DAO.TableDef
    Dim aTableName As String
    Dim aForeignTableName As String
    Dim aString As String
    Dim count As Integer

    count = 0
    Set aDB = CurrentDb

    For Each aTD In aDB.TableDefs
      Debug.Print aTD.Name
      Debug.Print aTD.Connect
      Debug.Print ""
      count = count + 1
    Next
    Debug.Print "There are " & count & " table defs."
End Sub
```

Additionally, you don't need `()` when you assign the `CurrentDb` object :

```
    Set aDB = CurrentDb
```

Answer (score -1):

My experience is that when calling a function or subroutine in VBA, enclosing your parameters (or lack thereof) in parentheses will cause this error.

There are two ways I know of to handle this:

1. Just don't use parentheses and always call the sub or function without them. This is fine if you are going from "PrintTableDefs()" to "PrintTableDefs" but can be problematic if the call is nested in a control structure or as another parameter.
2. Keep your parentheses, because you like parentheses and they remind you of C based language syntax, which helps you forget you are using the sadness of VBA. In that case, always assign the value of a function to a variable "result = PrintTableDefs()" and always use the Call keyword when invoking subroutines.

As an aside: your function returns no value. You should probably replace it with a subroutine, which is done by just replacing the word "Function" with the word "Sub".

Comment: Other than snark, can somebody explain why this is downvoted? To my ignorant eyes it is effectively the same answer as Thomas G posted, which is absolutely correct.